# Python: finding a pathway through lists using recursion

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion, math

Using python I am trying to figure out how I find a 'route' from one number in a list to a number found in another list.

For example, if I have the lists:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [4,5,6,7]
C = [7,8,9,10]
```

The route from 1 to 10 would be A -> B -> C, as 4 is in A and B and 7 is in B and C. I am trying to figure out how I would approach finding and recording the route from one value to another for a problem with a much larger number of lists with more elements where not every list shares the ideal common elements. I think I need to use recursion but can't seem to come up with a solution. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem seems to be the same than finding the shortest path in a graph. Your question is still imprecise though: should A connect to B because 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 are in A and then 4 is both in A and B ? or would that still work if A = [1, 4] ?

Comment: It would still work if A = [1, 4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'C': [7, 8, 9, 10]}
def find_path(start, end, c = [], seen = []):
   _r = [a for a, b in d.items() if any(i in b for i in d[start]) and a not in seen]
   if end in _r:
      yield c+[end]
   else:
      for i in _r:
        yield from find_path(i, end, c = c+[i], seen=seen+[start])


print(min(find_path('A', 'C', c = ['A']), key=len))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

This will work on larger input:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'C': [7, 8, 9, 10], 'D':[30, 45, 23], 'F':[10, 11, 12, 13], 'G':[13, 14, 15]}
print(min(find_path('A', 'G', c = ['A'], seen=['A']), key=len))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'G']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, I suggest the following approach

- create a graph where each node represents one of those lists
- for every number in every list, if that number is present in another list create a connection between the nodes
- for query, (1) find the start node, (2) find the end node, and (3) use a shortest path algorithm, for example from [`networkX`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html)